# Flow Import Error: Non-existent Layout Release UUID upon Re-upload

Tags: json, python-3.x, machine-learning, file-upload

I’m seeing errors when I try to upload my flow to the Hyperscience application (v34.0.3) - can anyone who has experience using the Hyperscience product assist with this? It claims

```
System setting referenced by input key "layout_release_uuid" does not exist.
```

I had just made some changes to the flow from a prior import and now it seems like I'm stuck. I tried reverting my changes to what I had initially uploaded and I'm still seeing this error, not sure what I'm missing or what else to try.

[error dialog contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1zzT.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several reasons why flow JSON uploads might fail or throw validation errors. Outlined below are some possible explanations:

1. The version of flow is incompatible with the Hyperscience application version installed.
2. The flow JSON contains multiple blocks identified by the same reference name. Each block must have its own unique reference name.
3. The flow being imported was previously associated with a layout_release_uuid that it is not able to match against in the instance.

You're likely seeing this particular error because Hyperscience flows are linked to releases and the flow has unlinked from the release upon re-uploading.

There could be other reasons too. Checking the logs would be a good first step. I am a consistent user of Hyperscience and typically reach out to flows.sdk@hyperscience.com when running into issues that I cannot debug myself.